# Qt C++ Data from a selected row

Tags: c++, qt

My row has 5 columns and I need the data from the last column. I've written the below function. This function should return the element from the last column of the selected row, but unfortunately, after debug I've noticed that my function only reads the first column. Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
QString MainWindow::getIDNumberFromSelectedRow(const QModelIndexList indexes)
{
    QStringList selected_text;
    foreach(QModelIndex current,indexes)
    {
        QVariant data = model->data(current);
        QString text = data.toString();
        selected_text.append(text);
        qDebug() << text;
    }

    QString idNumber = selected_text.last();
    return idNumber;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to verify what does `indexes` contain?

Comment: Being a single selection the `indexes` contains one item.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand then. If `indexes` contains only one item then why do you expect your `foreach` loop to run more than one time? It will always iterate only once, and `selected_text` will always contain only one item.

Comment: Try to print also `current.column()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly, indexes, and thus, current(s) refers to the first column of the model.
What if you refer directly to a specific item, e.g:

```
model->data(model->index(current.row(), 4))
```

I don't know if this work, anyway I hope it'll help